# How to setup environemnt to load python library?

Tags: python, import, module, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to import [pyroscope module](http://code.google.com/p/pyroscope/wiki/WriteYourOwnScripts) which is residing in my `~/lib/pyroscope` directory. The example [here](https://pyroscope.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyrocore/docs/examples/rt_cron_throttle_seed) shows that the script use `from pyrocore.scripts import base`. I don't see any tricks based on `imp.load_source`. So I am kinda puzzled - what kind of environment I have to build in order to import this module(*without relocating the library*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that `~/lib` is in the path python uses to look for libraries. One way to do this is set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in a shell:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/lib
```

Alternatively, you can change the path in your script before the `import`:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.expanduser('~/lib'))
```

For more information, please have a look at [The Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) in the documentation.